# Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit when Weather was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, type-mismatch

I am working on an Android Weather application and I am getting the error described in the title.  The function that is causing this error is a repository that is calling some weather data.  I have a helper class called DataOrException which is:

```
        class DataOrException<T, Boolean, E>(
            var data: T? = null,
            var loading: Kotlin.Boolean? = null,
            var e: E? = null
)
```

The function that is calling this class is a coroutine that is getting the weather information from repository which is using Injection to return the class.  Here's the function:

```
        suspend fun getWeather(cityQuery: String, units: String): DataOrException<Weather, Boolean, Exception> {
            val response = try {
                 api.getWeather(query = cityQuery, units = units)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                 Log.d("REX", "getWeather: $e")
                 return DataOrException(e = e)
            }
            return DataOrException(data = response) //Error occurs here.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Comment: Can you please post the code for `api` class that you're accessing here?

Comment: `code @Singleton
interface WeatherApi {
    @GET(value = "/cities/cityID=Chelsea")
    suspend fun getWeather(
        @Query("q") query: String,
        @Query("units") units: String = "imperial")
} `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getWeather` function in `WeatherApi` is not returning anything so it's basically a kotlin `Unit`. But,  In your repository `return DataOrException(data = response)` here `data` is expected to be of type `Weather`. That's why the error.

**Solution:**

Return `Weather` from `WeatherApi` function `getWeather` & keep everything else as it was.

```
interface WeatherApi {

    @GET(value = "/cities/cityID=Chelsea")
    suspend fun getWeather(@Query("q") query: String, @Query("units") units: String = "imperial") : Weather
}
```

**OR**

================

Change `data` type to `Unit` by changing to `: DataOrException<Unit, Boolean, Exception>`

```
suspend fun getWeather(
        cityQuery: String,
        units: String
    ): DataOrException<Unit, Boolean, Exception> {
        val response = try {
            api.getWeather(query = cityQuery, units = units)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("REX", "getWeather: $e")
            return DataOrException(e = e)
        }
        return DataOrException(data = response)
    }
```